# Multivariable Taylor series expansion for Lucas-Kanade optical flow derivation

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am learning about Lucas-Kanade optical flow which is an algorithm used in computer vision to track movement of objects between frames of images.

So it starts with a point in an 2D image with an intensity $I$, given by the function $I(x,y,t)$, where $t$ is the time. In the next time step, the point will have an intensity of $I(x+\Delta x,\ y+\Delta y,\ t+\Delta t)$

Now a Taylor expansion is done on the new intensity and truncated to the linear terms
$$I(x+\Delta x,\ y+\Delta y,\ t+\Delta t) \approx I(x,\ y,\ t)+I_x\Delta x+I_y\Delta y+I_t\Delta t $$
where $I_x, I_y$ and $I_t$ are the partial derivatives of $I$ with respect to $x, y, t$ respectively.

I don't understand how this Taylor expansion was made. I know for a multivariable function, for e.g. 2 variables, the Taylor expansion centered around $(a, b)$ up to the linear terms is:
$$f(x,y) \approx f(a,b) + f_x(a,b)(x-a) + f_y(a,b)(y-b)$$
Applying that to the intensity equation, if I center around $x+\Delta x$, I get
$$I(x+\Delta x,\ y+\Delta y,\ t+\Delta t) \approx I(x+\Delta x,\ y+\Delta y,\ t+\Delta t)+I_x|_{x+\Delta x}\cdot \Delta x+I_y|_{y+\Delta y}\cdot \Delta y+I_t|_{t+\Delta t}\cdot\Delta t $$

If I center around $x$ instead, then the partial derivatives of $I$ would be w.r.t $x+\Delta x$, $t+\Delta t$, $t+\Delta t$. I'm not sure how to get the expression desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite your formula
$$
f(x,y) \approx f(a,b) + f_x(a,b)(x-a) + f_y(a,b)(y-b)
$$
for the case where $f$ is a function of three variables:
$$
\tag{1} f(x,y,t) \approx f(a,b,c) + f_x(a,b,c)(x-a) + f_y(a,b,c) (y - b) + f_t(a,b,c)(t - c).
$$
If you understand that equation, you're in good shape. This is basically identical to the equation you want to derive. The only difference is that things are named differently. Just rename your variables so that $x$ is replaced with $x + \Delta x$, $y$ is replaced with $y + \Delta y$, $t$ is replaced with $t + \Delta t$, $a$ is replaced with $x$, $b$ is replaced with $y$, $c$ is replaced with $t$, and $f$ is replaced with $I$. Then equation (1) becomes
$$
I(x + \Delta x, y + \Delta y, t + \Delta t) \approx I(x,y,t) + I_x(x,y,t) \Delta x + I_y(x,y,t) \Delta y + I_t(x,y,t) \Delta t.
$$

Comment: If I replace for $x$ with $x+\Delta x$ in equation (1), would I not also need to change the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x+\Delta x$ instead of just with respect to $x$?

Comment: Oh is it because $\Delta x$ is a constant, therefore taking $f$ w.r.t $x$ is the same as taking it w.r.t $x + \Delta x$ ?